# Qemu: can I set the serial number on a virtual SCSI device?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, scsi, qemu

I'm using libvirt+KVM+Qemu on Ubuntu 11.04.  I have some scsi devices like this:

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
  <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/shared-01-02-00.img'/>
  <target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>
  <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' unit='0'/>
</disk>
```

The show up in the virtual machine as e.g. `/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi0-0-0`

For my management purposes, I would like to be able to assigned an arbitrary 'serial number' to the virtual devices, which would show up when `scsi_id` is run on the block device from inside the virtual machine.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked over the [libvirt docs](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsDisks) and found this:

> **serial**
>        If present, this specify serial number of virtual hard drive. For example, it may look like WD-WMAP9A966149.

So the XML block you have above would become:

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
  <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/shared-01-02-00.img'/>
  <target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>
  <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' unit='0'/>
  <serial>some-arbitrary-serial</serial>
</disk>
```

Comment: Nice: bit of experimentation required, but with this set, I get the ID passed through in the output of scsi_id when I use the "-p 0x80" flag.  Thanks, I feel silly for missing this in the docs :-)

Comment: Awesome.  Glad it worked.  Good to know about the "-p 0x80" flag too.

Comment: Can this be done directly with `qemu` command line instead of libvirt?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: that is possible if you use the `-device` command line parameter to explicitly specify how the disk image is attached to the virtual machine. There's an example at https://gist.github.com/ndunks/39bbf227f53fcaac5c1e7bf8fa53d930 : use something like `-drive if=none,id=disk00,format=qcow2,file=tmp/disk1.qcow2 -device "ide-hd,drive=disk00,serial=00000000000000000001,model=VMware Virtual IDE Hard Drive"`. I don't know if that's correct or actually the best way, but it worked for me.